# how to record stream video using C# wpf (writablebitmap)

Tags: c#, wpf

i want to record a streaming video which is placed on image. and also i want to take snapshot of the streaming video . i am using Writable-bitmap to streaming the video. please help me to solve this query. thank you in advance...!

```
private void DrawFrame(WriteableBitmap bitmap, VideoBuffer videoBuffer, PlaybackStatistics statistics) {
            VerifyAccess();
            if (IsPaused) {
                return;
            }
            bitmap.Lock();
            try {

                if (_recording)
                {

                  // please help me for recording code 

                }


                using (var md = videoBuffer.Lock()) {

                    bitmap.WritePixels(
                        new Int32Rect(0, 0, videoBuffer.width, videoBuffer.height),
                        md.value.scan0Ptr, videoBuffer.size, videoBuffer.stride,
                        0, 0
                    );
                }
            } finally {
                bitmap.Unlock();
            }
            fpsCaption.Text = statistics.avgRenderingFps.ToString("F1");
            noSignalPanel.Visibility =
                statistics.isNoSignal ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;

        }
```

Comment: Do you need to record the _stream_ or the decoded video?

Comment: record the stream

Comment: Then write the bytes to disc as they arrive? You don't get it smaller and faster.

Comment: actually , i dont know how to do it. thats why m asking.